# how to change address Bar Url dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, browser

we have an angular application, my page having, more than 10 stories, I want to change address bar URL dynamically when user scroll to that particular story, please advise some solution, I searched but did not find a proper solution ... than

Comment: Can you share some code ??

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to make parts of page to have unique URL, you can achieve the same by dividing your page into several section and assign `unique` URL to that each section. Suppose your html looks like below, then you can navigate to each section by using router `navigate` method or `routerLink` directive

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="section-body">...</div>
  <div id="section-some-other-content">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

**routerLink**

```
<a [routerLink]="['mydefaultroute']" fragment="header">Header section</a>
```

**navigate**

```
this._router.navigate( ['/mydefaultroute' ], {fragment: 'header'});
```

Comment: actually, I want to change the address bar URL, when I reach or scroll to that particular story article(Div).

Comment: @therightdoctors if you don't have ID given to a section, and try the above code,, it should work